# Fatal Error message in log file

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-loader

i have a major error message generated in my log file as i tried loading with sql loader

i created a control file named Ad2.ctl with this

and the loading command with

```
sqlldr scott/tiger@MYDB CONTROL='Ad2.ctl' LOG='Ad2.log'
```

the content of the file include the following sample

After runing the sql loader command i get a long list of error and the ADDRESS table was not populated.

the errors include the following

```
SQL*Loader: Release 10.2.0.3.0 - Production on Wed Sep 12 08:47:28 2012

 Copyright (c) 1982, 2005, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

 Control File:   Ad2.ctl
 Data File:      Abbeyruntest2.csv
  Bad File:     Abbeyruntest2.bad
  Discard File: Abbeyruntest2.dis 
 (Allow all discards)

Number to load: ALL
Number to skip: 0
Errors allowed: 50
Bind array:     64 rows, maximum of 256000 bytes
Continuation:    none specified
Path used:      Conventional

Table ADDRESS, loaded from every logical record.
Insert option in effect for this table: APPEND


Record 2: Rejected - Error on table ADDRESS, column ADDRESSAREA.
Column not found before end of logical record (use TRAILING NULLCOLS)
Record 3: Rejected - Error on table ADDRESS, column ADDRESSAREA.
Column not found before end of logical record (use TRAILING NULLCOLS)
```

Appologies for posting the long errors as am a newbee and am confused with it.

Comment: you need to show 2 records from your CSV...

Comment: Is that really sample data from your file, or just your explanation of it? Based on the control file it should be comma-separated so please show some actual data from the file. It sounds like you have more columns in the control file than in the data file. And the record-1 rejection suggests there's a header row in the data, is that right?

Comment: @ Alex Poole, there is a header row in it. i have updated it with the commas.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the problem lies in the quotes in you csv file.

I found an article [here](http://www.freelists.org/post/oracle-l/sqlloader-load-records-with-quotes,1) on how to load such files.

```
LOAD DATA
APPEND INTO TABLE testing
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
  a
 ,b  "replace ( :b ,'"' ,'' )"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your CSV file does not correspond at all with your control file. You have way too many commas in your CSV file - each comma delimits a new field, according to the FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' clause. I modified your data thusly, and it worked:

```
1,FLAT,                    ,1  ,Abesinia Passage   , 
2,Flat e-1,Edmund's Home   ,1a ,Arena's Palace Lane, 
3,flat 1,`Anderson's House',11a,                   ,Laguna Estate
```

If you can't modify your CSV file, then you'll need to define FILLER fields in your control file so that the field specifications line up with the actual data.